# Generating and viewing PDF using c# and react

Tags: c#, reactjs, pdf

I am working on the project to generate a pdf file based on some user input and information in the database, and I am looking for some guidance on how to execute the project and what frameworks to use. The project consists of three main parts: a website, server and database. The website's purpose is to gather data from the user and send it to the server. Once server receives the input, additional data is retrieved from the database, modified, and then combined together with the user input. The combined data is then used to generate a pdf document which is about 30 pages long. It is worth noting almost every page in the document is unique and has pictures. Next, pdf file is displayed on the website where it could be modified and downloaded by the user.

The website is written in React. In addition, I am planning on using `pdf-lib.js` to view and modify pdf.

The server is written in .NET 8. `QuestPDF` library looks very compelling as it has clear api and has good performance, however, I do not have any experience with it. Another solution that I am somewhat familiar with is to use html template stored on server, bind it to the model, and then generate pdf from it. Though, I think it might be more intensive process compared to the first approach.

I would like to hear your opinion and suggestions on my proposed approach to this project. Any help is appreciated and feel free to ask for more details. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Creating PDF's is easy; creating "reports" is hard. Once you have a report (i.e. integrated with a "report writer"), you can start asking about creating PDF's (which means "exporting" the report to PDF). As pointed out, "modifying" is not just another BTW.

Comment: Actually I had a similar use case, (vanilla js instead of react), my solution was using [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org) client-side and server-side with a few tweaks, since you already use react (nodejs) you will have no trouble at all using it server side also. Right now I am migrating server-side reports to QuestPDF, which uses a similar "logic" to create PDFs as pdfmake but is faster than the implementation I have for pdfmake-server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have firsthand experience with either of the libraries you use, but I do have a similar workflow that I use different tools for. This isn't an endorsement or recommendation of any particular tool, just an explanation of my workflow that may give you some ideas and/or validation.

Server side, I use either [PDFSharp](https://www.pdfsharp.net/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) or [Aspose](https://www.aspose.com/) to generate PDFs. PDFSharp can draw on the page like a canvas, with familiar functions like rectangles, circles, text boxes, etc. The drawback is that you have to handle almost all the layout yourself. As you mention your application is for generating reports, I assume in some kind of tabular format, that could be challenging as you will be doing a lot of the work of a word processor.

Instead for something with potentially complicated layout I use Aspose first to create a Microsoft Word DOCX document, and then save it to PDF. The Aspose document writer lets you lay out tables, paragraphs, styles, etc. much more naturally than with low level drawing functions. However quickly looking at QuestPDF, it appears to have much richer layout capability than what I use, so it's entirely possible it will suit your needs. Ultimately if you're able to use it and like the results you should do so.

In any case once the PDF is generated, you either: (1) save it to the server storage somewhere and provide a download link for later, or (2) serve it up immediately. The latter approach may not be ideal for 30 page reports though, which could take a few seconds or more to generate, especially if they're image heavy which you indicate. So your approach to save them in a list for the user to download sounds sensible.

You also mention editing; at least one of the comments mentions this seems unusual here, and I agree, unless you're talking about metadata of some kind. It wouldn't make obvious sense for reports to be editable if they're reporting past data. However if you do need editing capabilities I'm not imagining, you might do well to consider exposing server-side REST APIs for this purpose and continuing to use one library and codebase for both generation and editing. This will make your project much easier to maintain.

That covers server side. Client side, unless you have a requirement that the report be viewable inside the application context, you might consider simply opening the PDF in a new tab (`window.open(url,'_blank');`). Every modern browser has a built in PDF viewer. Chrome uses PDFium (an excellent native library) and Firefox uses [PDF.JS](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) which runs in the JS runtime. Either is as good or better than anything you could do in Javascript within your own React application.

The only part of your proposed workflow I would question is PDF-LIB. This is a client-side Javascript library for creating and editing PDFs, not for viewing them in the browser. If you have a need to display the PDF in the application window (and opening in a new tab isn't sufficient), then you'd need to use something like [PDF.JS](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/). PDF.JS has a built-in viewer with some rich but generic functionality, however, it also has lower level functions for making a more complex viewer. It does not have editing functionality though; I don't believe you'll find a browser-side tool that has both.